# Initial value for attr_reader in the class level

Tags: ruby

I want to initialize `my_attr_reader`. Changing `attr_reader` to `cattr_reader` doesn't help because there is such a method `cattr_reader` for some reason.

How can I do that?

```
module Mod1
  def method1
    puts "method1 from Mod1"
  end
end

MyClass = Object.new
class << MyClass
  include Mod1

  attr_reader :my_attr_reader
  my_attr_reader = "111" # doesn't get initialized

  def initialize
    self.my_attr_reader = "123" # doesn't get initialized
  end

  def my_class1_method1
    puts "MyClass method1"
  end
end

MyClass.my_class1_method1
MyClass.method1
p MyClass.my_attr_reader # nil
```

P.S. Why does `include` work here, whereas `extend` doesn't, even so it should be exactly the opposite?

Comment: What in gods name are you trying to do here? What about `class MyClass; attr_reader :my_attr_reader; end`? Why are you using `MyClass = Object.new` and `class << MyClass`?

Comment: @meagar, what's your business?

Comment: It seems like you are asking two questions here (why the `attr_reader` stuff isn't working, and details about `include` vs `extend`). For the future, I would recommending splitting this into two separate questions.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy, it just seems so.

Comment: `self.my_attr_reader = "123"` will not work because you have no method to handle this. You defined an `attr_reader` which creates a getter method but not a setter e.g. `my_attr_reader=` so you will get an `undefined method` error.

Comment: @engineersmnky, the question is what to do.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp yes I understand what the question is that's why I mentioned it in a comment and not an answer but if you want to set an attribute this way you need an `attr_accessor` which will created both the getter and setter methods where as an `attr_reader` only creates a getter method. I was responding to your portion of "#does not get initialized" which first off requires initialization which is not happening when you call the class but rather when you call initialize on the class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here, so I'll split this up into sections.

### A note about `cattr_reader`

`cattr_reader` would probably be useful for you, but it is a part of Rails, not Ruby. You will not be able to use this in Ruby code without first including the right parts of Rails.

### How to use `attr_reader`

Your main problem here is that `attr_reader` and `cattr_reader` create instance and class variables respectively, but you are using local variables instead. Instance variables start with `@`, and class variables start with `@@`. Class variables have odd and confusing behaviors, and `cattr_reader` isn't built into Ruby as I mentioned above, so I would recommend using `attr_reader` on the class level.

### Why does `include` work here, whereas `extend` doesn't, even so it should be exactly the opposite?

`extend` adds in class-level methods, while `include` includes instance methods. You are defining `method` as an instance method of `Mod1`, so you should be using `include`.

Comment: `You are defining method as an instance method of Mod1, so you should be using include.` - but I'm defining it on the class level.

Comment: Using it on the class level is your intention, but you need to include it on the instant level because you are using `class << MyClass`, which treats the code inside as if it were an instance.